# (C++) Need help making splash screen for reprapdiscount smart controller 4x20 LCD display - EDITED

Tags: c++, printing, 3d, arduino, lcd

I recently purchased a delta 3d printer kit that uses the marlin software, MKS mini (kossel) main board (uses Arduino bootloader & Marlin Firmware), and reprapdiscount smart controller LCD display (4 rows x 20 characters).

I have almost zero programming experience, and I would like some help to create a "splash screen" that is called on boot only, then goes back to the status screen after a certain time. I have already scoured the internet on how to do this, but the only ones that had any viable options were for the FULL GRAPHICS version LCD display - which is not what I have. I have found the .cpp file used for this specific LCD display - however with my limited programming knowledge, I cannot figure out how to add a splash screen on start.

I'm pretty sure that I have to create a void function at the beginning of the menu implementation (see below), but i'm not sure what / how to call it so that it starts first, then switches to the status screen afterwards. I can write the pseudo code for it, but don't know the full code...

*side-note: I just realized that in the menu items, it shows the reference variable of the text, which is actually contained in another file called language.h*

**PSEUDO CODE of what I would like it to do:**

```
//start->boot printer
static void splashscreen()
{
    /*splashlines are defined in language.h file*/
    static void splashline1(); // hello
    static void splashline2(); // world
    static void splashline3(); // i'm
    static void splashline4(); // here!
    wait 3 seconds;
    switch to -> static void lcd_status_screen();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Unfortunately the post is limited to 30,000 characters, and posting the original code will put me at over 50,000... so I will try to post

**relevant code snippets:**

*THANKS IN ADVANCE!!*

---

**EDITED**

---

~ LCD status screen code ~

```
#ifdef ULTIPANEL
static float manual_feedrate[] = MANUAL_FEEDRATE;
#endif // ULTIPANEL

/* !Configuration settings */

//Function pointer to menu functions.
typedef void (*menuFunc_t)();

uint8_t lcd_status_message_level;
char lcd_status_message[LCD_WIDTH+1] = WELCOME_MSG;

/** forward declerations **/

void copy_and_scalePID_i();
void copy_and_scalePID_d();

/* Different menus */
static void lcd_status_screen();
#ifdef ULTIPANEL
  extern bool powersupply;
  static void lcd_main_menu();
  static void lcd_tune_menu();
  static void lcd_prepare_menu();
  static void lcd_move_menu();
  static void lcd_control_menu();
  static void lcd_control_temperature_menu();
  static void lcd_control_temperature_preheat_pla_settings_menu();
  static void lcd_control_temperature_preheat_abs_settings_menu();
  static void lcd_control_motion_menu();
```

~ **EDITED** Start of coding ~

```
menuFunc_t currentMenu = lcd_status_screen; /* function pointer to the currently active menu */
uint32_t lcd_next_update_millis;
uint8_t lcd_status_update_delay;
uint8_t lcdDrawUpdate = 2;                  /* Set to none-zero when the LCD needs to draw, decreased after every draw. Set to 2 in LCD routines so the LCD gets atleast 1 full redraw (first redraw is partial) */

//prevMenu and prevEncoderPosition are used to store the previous menu location when editing settings.
menuFunc_t prevMenu = NULL;
uint16_t prevEncoderPosition;
//Variables used when editing values.
const char* editLabel;
void* editValue;
int32_t minEditValue, maxEditValue;
menuFunc_t callbackFunc;

// placeholders for Ki and Kd edits
float raw_Ki, raw_Kd;

/* Main status screen. It's up to the implementation specific part to show what is needed. As this is very display dependend */
static void lcd_status_screen()
{
    if (lcd_status_update_delay)
        lcd_status_update_delay--;
    else
        lcdDrawUpdate = 1;
    if (lcdDrawUpdate)
    {
        lcd_implementation_status_screen();
        lcd_status_update_delay = 10;   /* redraw the main screen every second. This is easier then trying keep track of all things that change on the screen */
    }
#ifdef ULTIPANEL
    if (LCD_CLICKED)
    {
        currentMenu = lcd_main_menu;
        encoderPosition = 0;
        lcd_quick_feedback();
    }

    // Dead zone at 100% feedrate
    if ((feedmultiply < 100 && (feedmultiply + int(encoderPosition)) > 100) ||
            (feedmultiply > 100 && (feedmultiply + int(encoderPosition)) < 100))
    {
        encoderPosition = 0;
        feedmultiply = 100;
    }

    if (feedmultiply == 100 && int(encoderPosition) > ENCODER_FEEDRATE_DEADZONE)
    {
        feedmultiply += int(encoderPosition) - ENCODER_FEEDRATE_DEADZONE;
        encoderPosition = 0;
    }
    else if (feedmultiply == 100 && int(encoderPosition) < -ENCODER_FEEDRATE_DEADZONE)
    {
        feedmultiply += int(encoderPosition) + ENCODER_FEEDRATE_DEADZONE;
        encoderPosition = 0;
    }
    else if (feedmultiply != 100)
    {
        feedmultiply += int(encoderPosition);
        encoderPosition = 0;
    }

    if (feedmultiply < 10)
        feedmultiply = 10;
    if (feedmultiply > 999)
        feedmultiply = 999;
#endif//ULTIPANEL
}
```

Comment: What is exactly is your question?

Comment: I wish to make a splash screen for the LCD display at the beginning of the boot for 3 seconds (see pseudo code for reference), then switch to the status screen. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Well, that's quite a tall order for ONE question on StackOverflow. No one is going to offer to write your code for you. Try to figure out exactly where the gaps in your knowledge are and ask specific questions about those gaps.

Comment: Joel - I looked through the code again and found that the previous code I posted really wasn't related to what I was requesting. I apologize for this, however I DO need help with the coding as I have no idea what to even look for in as far as variables and codes for what i want to do. I am not looking for a complete handout, even the names of code variables to use will do, I can google those and play around with it from there.

Answer (score 0):

As Joel Cornett suggested, look up the gaps in knowledge and ask specifically about those gaps. In that case, it seems what you need is the following:

1. How to code a timed pause for the "splash" to display.
2. Where to initialize the code you want (I think you may have overlooked it, as I don't think see it in the code you posted).
3. How to make the code proceed to the status screen without looping on itself.

Try to edit your post / split your questions into individual posts. You may get a better response rate from that.